# C# project loading different version of system assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, assemblies, pdb-files

I'm trying to debug into a class in the System.Web.dll assembly, but I can't make it work. I've tried to add the SymbolSource servers but none of them return the .pdb I need for line-debugging the framework. By analyzing the output of the `Modules` pane in debug time, I can see it's loading different assemblies from the project's target .NET version (4.5):

[image: modules window showing Version column different from project's version]

So I suspect the reason the PDB isn't being loaded is because the assembly being loaded has version 4.6. Is there a setting I'm missing here?

Comment: Nothing unusual about seeing 4.6 assemblies getting used, that's the version you have on your machine.  But your .NET version is old, version 4.6.57 was a Release Candidate from May 2015.  You can't expect consistent symbol support for pre-release versions, time to update to the RTM release.  I have no trouble getting the PDB for mine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your VS isn't configured properly to debug such sources.

Find out more here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html

Comment: After trying that, it still says for the assembly I want to load (System.Web.dll) "Cannot find or open the PDB file". Almost all the other assemblies load their symbols just fine.